# changing size of 2D array with vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I always have trouble with Arrays which is why I usually avoid them but this time I'm trying to get my head round them

I'm trying to change the size of my Global Array inside vba

I have declared it using `Public UseArr() As String`

Now I've written a function that searches an SQL table and returns user information as a record set.

I want to take this record set and put it into my Global Array

This is the bit of code I've written for populating it

```
a = 0
If Not Not UseArr Then
    For i = 0 To UBound(UseArr)
        If StrComp(UseArr(i, 0), rs("Alias")) = 0 Then a = 1
    Next i
    b = i
Else
    b = 0
End If

If a = 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve UseArr(0 To b, 0 To 10)
    With rs
        If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
            For j = 0 To 10
                If Not rs(j) = "" Then
                    UseArr(b, j) = rs(j)
                Else
                    UseArr(b, j) = "Null"
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    End With
End If
```

The idea being if the user is already in there it doesn't populate, and if not it populates.

It works fine for initialising the Array however when I go to put in a second user it throws a resize error.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Tom

**Update with Dictionary Attempt**

```
If UseList Is Nothing Then
    Set UseList = New Dictionary
    MsgBox "Created New"
End If

If UseList.Exists(rs("Alias")) Then

    Dim temp()
    For i = 0 To 10
        temp(i) = rs(i + 1)
    Next i

    With UseList
        .Add Key:=rs("Alias"), Item:=temp
    End With
End If

Debug.Print UseList
```

Comment: I sort of remember a long time a go reading that you can't resize the inside dimension of 2D arrays. I'm hoping I'm wrong

Answer (score 2):

You can only `Redim Preserve` the last dimension of a multi-dimensional array - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251578(v=office.15).aspx). Have you considered using a `Collection` or `Dictionary` instead?

edit: using the code you've posted above, here's how you would display element 4 from the array associated with the key "tom"

`MsgBox UseList("tom")(4)`

or equivalently

`MsgBox UseList.Item("tom")(4)`

Comment: That's what I was hoping I was wrong about. I don't know much about Collections/Dictionaries but I thought they could only be 1D? Could I use a dictionary globally?

Comment: Dictionary has a "Unique Key" and a "Value". You can declare it globally and pass it as a parameter as with any other variable / data structure. I've just started learning and it's very useful. You need to import the Microsoft Scripting Runtime in your spreadsheet, but that's only a tick box anyway!

Comment: Thanks guys - I'm getting there but I'm struggling with storing more then one value against any key. I think I'm understanding it correctly but not 100%. To do this I've passed an array into the item under the related key. But I can't for the life of me get it to recall. Any pointers?

Comment: I've added some code for extracting an array element from the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you have some explanation about how a Dictionary object works and some of its attributes and functions.

I think it's the best to reach your goal because they are so easy to use, fast and efficient.

First you have to import the `mscorlib.dll` into the Project References.

After you can use something like this to declare the dictionary:

```
Dim UseDict As Dictionary
Set UseDict = New Dictionary
```

To know if the Key you're searching is not in the Dictionary and then add the new user:

```
If Not UseDict.Exists(Key) Then
   UseDict.Item(Key) = 1
End If
```

The Value is not important here, but if you wanted to count how many times a key appears somewhere, you could increment the value when `UseDict.Exists(Key) = True`.
That's what the Dictionaries, Hash-maps or Maps stand for: count and search efficiently.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks will have a look - I'm populating the array as the information is on a remote sql server. This can run very slowly for people using it on our VPN. I also don't want to just pull the whole table for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for this. To be honest I'm quite confused. I've got this far as to what you've put above but can only get it to store one value per key (I need it to store 10 more values after the key) - I looked at storing an array into the item with those values but now can't retrieve it. Any help? :S

Comment: Can you paste the code somewhere to see if there's any mistake?

Comment: Hi Eva - Have updated my original post with my attempt

Answer (score 0):

I attach a code with some corrections. I think the problem is that you are trying to access to an array as if it was a variable. That means you have to loop through the item of a key.

I add comments to the code below:

**Update**

```
If UseList Is Nothing Then
    Set UseList = New Dictionary
    MsgBox "Created New"
End If

If UseList.Exists(rs("Alias")) Then
'i think is better to specify the data type and the dimension.
    Dim temp(10) as string
'if you loop from 0 to 10 the array will have 11 elements
    For i = 0 To 9
        temp(i) = rs(i + 1)
    Next i
'This will work also and looks nicer (in my opinion) than the method 
'you pasted, but if that worked anyway don't change it ;)
UseList(rs("Alias")).Item = temp

End If
```

Now, if you want to retrieve the result you must:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(UseList.Item(rs("Alias")) - 1
    Debug.Print UseList.Item(rs("Alias"))(i)
Next i
```

Give me feedback when you test the code, please :)